# Missing type specifier on a static function with a type

Tags: c++

My question relates to three files and how they relate to each other:
In one file I have a bunch of predefined types such as `Uint`, `int32`, etc.
In the other two I have a class that is used to categories exceptions (which is mostly static functions) and definitions for the class.

All of the types are in the file `Types.h`, with a macro which allows the types to be defined globally:

```
namespace Enigma {
    //Omitted Types
    typedef std::uint32_t Uint32;
    typedef std::string   string;
    //Omitted Types
}
#if defined(USING_GLOBAL_TYPES)
using namespace aNamespace;
#endif
```

In the other files I have the following (or similar to it anyway):

Header file:

```
#include "Types.h"

namespace Enigma {
class ExceptionCategory {
    typedef Uint32 CategoryID;

    static CategoryID GetIDFromName(const string& name) noexcept;
};
}
```

Source file:

```
Engima::ExceptionCategory::CategoryID Enigma::ExceptionCategory::GetIDFromName(const string& name) noexcept {
//Omitted Code
}
```

Now the problem lies within the Source file according to the error messages the Compiler is throwing at me which include the following:

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
>
> error C2511: 'Enigma::ExceptionCategory::IDType Enigma::ExceptionCategory::GetIDFromName(const int) noexcept': overloaded member function not found in 'Enigma::ExceptionCategory'

Edit: Major Rewording

Answer (score 1):

In the cpp file, remove the double colon before the namespace.

```
aNamespace::int32 aNamespace::aClass::aStaticFunction() noexcept {
    //does a thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple mistake:
Was missing the namespace `Enigma` before `string` in the source code.
It's unusual because it has been working fine for ages until suddenly it stopped working

```
Engima::ExceptionCategory::CategoryID Enigma::ExceptionCategory::GetIDFromName(const Enigma::string& name) noexcept {
    //Omitted Code
}
```

Comment: *"It's unusual because it has been working fine for ages until suddenly it stopped working"* Accidentally used `using namespace std;` in a header?

Comment: @Zeta I glad it works now and I'm not going to touch it and no wasn't using it